# Python Calculator in Tkinter - Functions auto-running

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a graphical calculator in Python 2.7.3 with Tkinter. I have set it up so when the user pushes the 'b' button it will print 'b' to the console. I do this by making a function that is passed a variable called 'key' which it then adds to the label. However, when I first start the program, it automatically calls the function and prints 'b' to the console. Whenever I click the button, it does nothing. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def addkey(self,key):
        print str(key)

    def removekey(self):
        if len(self.displaytext) > 0:
            self.displaytext = self.displaytext[0:-1]

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.maxlength = 20
        self.displaytext = ""

        self.frame1 = Frame(self)
        self.display = Label(self.frame1,textvariable=self.displaytext,width=self.maxlength+3,bg="black",fg="white",height=2)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.display.pack()

        self.frame2 = Frame(self)
        self.bksp = Button(self.frame2,text="b",width=4,height=2,command=self.addkey("b"))
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.bksp.pack()


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

app = Application()
app.mainloop()

try:
    root.destroy()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: It looks like people enjoy repeating this question, and other people enjoy repeating the answers :/

Comment: @mmgp -- I'm sure that I've answered it quite a few times.  But, it's a reasonably difficult one to come up with search terms that will take you to an appropriately already answered question.  Sometimes, it's easier to answer the question than to go searching for a duplicate -- That said, if you find a duplicate and vote-to-close or post a link, I'll happily vote to close this one as well :).

Answer (score 2):

`command = ...` expects to be passed a *function* (which accepts 0 arguments).  As it is, you are passing the *result* of a function (which is `None` in this case).

One easy way to do this is to use an [anonymous function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) to wrap around your function and call it appropriately:

```
command=lambda: self.addkey("b")
```

Or you could do it more verbosely:

```
def button_func():
    return self.addkey("b")
self.bksp = Button(self.frame2,text="b",width=4,height=2,command=button_func)
```

But this starts to get pretty verbose if you have 15 buttons each calling the same underlying function with slightly different arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `self.addkey` and assigning its result to the `command` argument.  Instead, you need to pass a function that can be called.

In other words, change

```
command=self.addkey("b")
```

to

```
command=lambda: self.addkey("b")
```

If `self.addkey` didn't need any additional arguments, you could just do `command=self.addkey`, but since that is not the case you need the `lambda`.